# Move kineticJS shape with keyboard

Tags: keyboard, html5-canvas, kineticjs, shapes

I want to move some shapes with the keyboard arrows. I've read some tutorials, but nothing have seemed to help me so far. I think the problem is how I've handled the keyboard event, so please take a look.

```
<div id="fullscreenDiv"/>

<script defer="defer">
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'fullscreenDiv',
        width: 1180,
        height: 700
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var gamepart = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 1180,
        height: 500,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });

    var statuspart = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 500,
        width: 1180,
        height: 100,
        fill: 'blue',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });

    var box1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 225,
        width: 130,
        height: 90,
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3
    });

    var box2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 400,
        y: 225,
        width: 130,
        height: 90,
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3
    });

    var line12 = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [230, 270, 400, 270],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3
    });

    var box3 = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 1400,
        y: 225,
        width: 130,
        height: 90,
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3
    });

    var line23 = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [530, 270, 1400, 270],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(gamepart);
    layer.add(statuspart);
    layer.add(box1);
    layer.add(box2);
    layer.add(line12);
    layer.add(box3);
    layer.add(line23);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);

    layer.draw();


    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) //Left Arrow Key
            box1.attrs.x -= 10;
        if (e.keyCode == 38) //Up Arrow Key
            box1.attrs.y += 10;
        if (e.keyCode == 39) //Right Arrow Key
            box1.x += 10;
        if (e.keyCode == 40) //Top Arrow Key
            box1.attributes.x -= 10;

        stage.draw();
    });


</script>
```

**Edit**

This is picture of the webpage, and I want to move the rectandgles with that's white inside.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Just use other API to change attributes:

```
    if (e.keyCode == 37) //Left Arrow Key
        box1.x(box1.x() - 10);
    if (e.keyCode == 38) //Up Arrow Key
        box1.y(box1.y() + 10);
    if (e.keyCode == 39) //Right Arrow Key
        box1.x(box1.x() + 10);
```

Comment: SuperB! What is the best way to move multiple shapes? lets say every white box and lines between them? I know i can use this method for every shape, but can I make some kind of group and move it, or should I maybe make a function that has every shape?

Comment: future reference for anyone, i.e fiddle to play with above code http://jsfiddle.net/xEsDZ/71/